# Split string in Array after specific delimited and New line

Tags: bash, split, yaml

```
$string="name: Destination Administrator
    description: Manage the destination configurations, certificates and subaccount trust.
    readOnly:
    roleReferences:
    - roleTemplateAppId: destination-xsappname!b62
      roleTemplateName: Destination_Administrator
      name: Destination Administrator"
```

I have above string each line is delimited by newline char, and I like to create array with two column after "-" as below

```
Col1                    col2
roleTemplateAppId       destination-xsappname!b62
roleTemplateName        Destination_Administrator
name                    Destination Administrator
```

I tried below but it is not returning correct array

```
IFS='- ' read -r -a arrstring <<< "$string"
echo "${arrstring [1]}"
```

Comment: Which shell scrip variant is this? You should tag your question [bash], [zsh], etc.

Comment: Sorry, I added as Bash

Comment: Your data is YAML, use a YAML parser. Bash/shell cannot parse YAML.

Comment: what do you mean by `array with two column`? is the first column supposed to be the index of the array?

Comment: Two dimensional Array with data shown in my example. Col1 and col2 with values shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- OP is unable to use a yaml parser (per Léa's comment)
- the input is guaranteed to have `\n` line endings (within the data)
- the `-` only shows up in the one location (as depicted in OP's sample input); otherwise we need a better definition of where to start parsing the data
- we're interested in parsing everything that follows the `-`
- data is to be parsed based on a `:` delimiter, with the first field serving as the index in an ***associative array***, while the 2nd field will be the value stored in the array
- leading/trailing spaces to be removed from array indexes and values

One `sed` idea for pulling out just the lines we're interested in:

```
$ sed -n '/- /,${s/-//;p}' <<< "${string}"
     roleTemplateAppId: destinationxsappname!b62
      roleTemplateName: Destination_Administrator
      name: Destination Administrator
```

Adding a few more bits to strip off leading/trailing spaces:

```
$ sed -n '/- /,${s/-//;s/^[ ]*//;s/[ ]*$//;s/[ ]*:[ ]*/:/;p}' <<< "${string}"                                          
roleTemplateAppId:destination-xsappname!b62
roleTemplateName:Destination_Administrator
name:Destination Administrator
```

From here we'll feed this to a `while` loop where we'll populate the associative array

```
unset      arrstring
declare -A arrstring                   # declare as an associative array

while IFS=':' read -r index value
do
    arrstring["${index}"]="${value}"
done < <(sed -n '/- /,${s/-//;s/^[ ]*//;s/[ ]*$//;s/[ ]*:[ ]*/:/;p}' <<< "${string}")
```

Leaving us with:

```
$ typeset -p arrstring
declare -A arrstring=([roleTemplateAppId]="destination-xsappname!b62" [name]="Destination Administrator" [roleTemplateName]="Destination_Administrator" )

$ for i in "${!arrstring[@]}"
do
    echo "$i : ${arrstring[$i]}"
done

roleTemplateAppId : destination-xsappname!b62
name : Destination Administrator
roleTemplateName : Destination_Administrator
```

Comment: This was great solution. Thank you for your help